# How to change the url in the fetch statement React JS using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm trying to make this ApiCalls class, which was working if I just plugged in a url into the fetch statement, but I'm trying to make it so that I can change the url depending on which button I press on the site. I want to call ApiCalls in the SearchButtons.js class where in each click function I'll specify the url I want to use. It's not working and it's definitely something to do with the props, idk how else to pass in the a

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      //url: {props.url}////////////////////////////// this doesnt work. 
//if i dont use brackets it compiles, but I get this error
//Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.url)//////////////////////////////////////////////
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.articles
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      console.log(items);
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <ArticleCard key={item.title} title={item.title} desc={item.description} imgsrc={item.urlToImage} url={item.url}/>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default ApiCalls;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ApiCalls from "./ApiCalls";
class SearchButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
    return (<ApiCalls url="myUrlHasMyAPIKeySoThisIsAPlaceHolder/>); ////////////////////////
    ///this is where I want to specify the url
  }
```

Comment: fetch(this.url)  =>  fetch(this.props.url)

Comment: in `SearchButton.js` in `<ApiCalls />` you are missing the closing quotation marks `"`. In your other component, you are no using the state in `cdm`; Do this inside the constructor `this.state = { ..., url: props.url }`. And in `componentDidMount() { fetch(this.state.url) {... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply doing this.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from "./ApiCalls";

class SearchButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
    return (<ApiCalls url="myUrl"/>); 
  }
....
```

And In Child Component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url){/* Access url from props */}
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.articles
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
....
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Hi, this definitely helps but I'm trying to render the ApiCalls in the handleClick function, but whenever I try to put a render command in it doesn't work. I tried putting the render function as a separate function that's called in handleClick also but it doesn't like it. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not possible you can't render a component inside a click handler.